# How to create a method for specific values in a column from a table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Issue: I am looking for a way to have separate notices for different values in a tables column.

I have order_status that has 3 separate values, created, cancelled, and charged.

I would like 3 separate notices for each when the columns are changed from a view.

a view will be something like:

```
<%= form_for @order, remote: true do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :order_status, value: "cancelled" %>
    <%= f.button type:'submit', class: "btn btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

This will change the column to "cancelled".

I then want to create a method like:

```
  def cancel_update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(params[:order_update])
        if user_signed_in?
          if @order.order_status = "cancelled"

            format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully cancelled.' }
            format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
          else
            format.html { render :edit }
            format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

But this method didn't work how i planned.  When i use this method, nothing happens when i click the button, no page reload, redirect, etc. I get the error: "The action 'update' could not be found for OrdersController"
(This was tested by taking out the original update method - which is below).

Now when i use this update method, it works but doesn't pin point the value update on the order_status only.

```
def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_params)
        if user_signed_in?
          format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully uploaded.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
        if buyer_signed_in?
          format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @order }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Here is another attempt that somehow didn't function:

```
  def order_cancel
    respond_to do |format|
      if @order.update(order_status)
        format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully cancelled.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end
    end
  end

private

def order_status
      params.permit(:order_status)
    end
```

How can I pin point the order_status values from the controller to allow me to have separate actions and notices when the values are changed by a end user?

Answer (score 0):

Given that you use the Rails form builder to generate the form's HTML

```
<%= form_for @order, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :order_status, value: "cancelled" %>
```

I would expect that the generated name of the input field is nested under `order`. That said you will need to follow these nesting when permitting the params:

```
def order_status
  params.require(:order).permit(:order_status)
end
```

When you are unsure how the parameters really look like you might want to have a look at the generated HTML structure of the form or you can look at the Rails logs for the `update` request to the application.

Answer (score 0):

So, those three lines are wrong:

```
  if @order.update(params[:order_update])
    if user_signed_in?
      if @order.order_status = "cancelled"
```

Should be:

```
  if user_signed_in?
    if @order.update(status: params[:order_status])
      if @order.order_status == "cancelled"
```

But actually should be `@order.update!(status: :cancelled)` in a `cancel` action, or at least have a state machine to validate that the user is not messing up the states of the orders.

Or like is expected by your form, those should be in a `update` method (not `cancel_update`)

The `update` method you posted doesn't make sense, it has a minimum of 2 renders, I think you meant to not have the `buyer_signed_in` section.

Comment: Thanks! ill give this a try in a few!